Rotate Slideshow Caption and Align Right
I found a slideshow I like here: https://codepen.io/AndresUris/pen/rGXpvE
What I wanted to do was add a title to the right of the image that was rotated...kind of like this: 90 degrees rotated text, flush to page top-right with CSS
So, I added a title and incorporated the text, but the alignment looks all wonky. I tried to fix it with some css, but I can't quite get it right.
The HTML:


    /* Slider */
    /* Slideshow container */
    #slide-container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 800px; /* responsiveness */
    }

    /* First element to be in block mode for responsiveness */
    #slide-first-element {
        display: block; /* to get the dimensions set */
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* Other element to be in absolute position */
    #slide-element-2,
    #slide-element-3 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    /* Style images */
    .slide-image {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Style text */
    .slide-text {
        position: absolute;
        right: -35%;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: white;
        width: 70%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    /* Animation settings for individual elements */
    /* For more images the animations have to be adjusted */
    #slide-first-element {
        animation: fade-1 10s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: fade-1 10s infinite;
    }

    #slide-element-2 {
        animation: fade-2 10s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: fade-2 10s infinite;
    }

    #slide-element-3 {
        animation: fade-3 10s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: fade-3 10s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes fade-1 {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        33% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        66% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes fade-2 {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        33% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        66% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    @keyframes fade-3 {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        33% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        66% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    /* example for a 4th slide */
    @keyframes fade-4 {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        25% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        75% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
 <div id="slide-container">
        <div id="slide-first-element">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?w=752&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Beautiful</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-element-2">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?w=750&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Amazing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-element-3">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498753427761-548428edfa67?w=889&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Incredible</p>
        </div>
    </div>



Anyone know what I can tweak to get this working? Once the text gets rotated, it's like the height becomes the width and left becomes right. But, even using that logic makes it hard to figure out. Is there something more straightforward I can use?
Thanks,
Josh

I suggest using separate tables for each pair of image and text. You can not achieve this directly when you have different images with different sizes.

I appreciate your suggestion! But, I haven’t used tables in ages, not even sure how I would go about that with tables, especially with different-sized images. Could you share an example somewhere that I could look at?

Don't rely on rotation, using writing-mode instead. I also remove a lot of useless code


#slide-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#slide-element-2,
#slide-element-3 {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slide-text {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: scale(-1);
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

#slide-first-element {
  animation: fade-1 10s infinite;
}

#slide-element-2 {
  animation: fade-2 10s infinite;
}

#slide-element-3 {
  animation: fade-3 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* example for a 4th slide */

@keyframes fade-4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<div id="slide-container">
  <div id="slide-first-element">
    <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?w=752&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
    <p class="slide-text">Beautiful</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slide-element-2">
    <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?w=750&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
    <p class="slide-text">Amazing</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slide-element-3">
    <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498753427761-548428edfa67?w=889&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
    <p class="slide-text">Incredible</p>
  </div>
</div>




Hey there, thank you! I did try ‘writing-mode’ but I couldn’t get that to work either. I know I tried several different slideshow scripts, so I might have missed it on this one! Thank you for simplifying the code, I usually go through it and remove unnecessary things after I know it’s going to work for me, and I just hadn’t gotten comfortable enough to do that just yet.



/* Slider */
/* Slideshow container */
#slide-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px; /* responsiveness */
}

/* First element to be in block mode for responsiveness */
#slide-first-element {
    display: block; /* to get the dimensions set */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* Other element to be in absolute position */
#slide-element-2,
#slide-element-3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* Style images */
.slide-image {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Style text */
.slide-text {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: white;
    width: 200px; /* Adjust the width according to your needs */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transform-origin: top right;
    transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-90deg);
    
    /* Vendor prefixes for older browsers */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: top right;
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: top right;
    -o-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-90deg);
}

/* Animation settings for individual elements */
/* For more images the animations have to be adjusted */
#slide-first-element {
    animation: fade-1 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fade-1 10s infinite;
}

#slide-element-2 {
    animation: fade-2 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fade-2 10s infinite;
}

#slide-element-3 {
    animation: fade-3 10s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fade-3 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade-1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-3 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* example for a 4th slide */
@keyframes fade-4 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
<div id="slide-container">
        <div id="slide-first-element">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?w=752&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Beautiful</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-element-2">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?w=750&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Amazing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-element-3">
            <img class="slide-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498753427761-548428edfa67?w=889&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
            <p class="slide-text">Incredible</p>
        </div>
    </div>




This is not responsive.

Yes, I was going to make some adjustments to the code once I got the rotation addressed. Thanks for pointing that out, I definitely want to make sure it’s responsive :-)
